# How to highlight current child page on custom sidebar menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a sidebar menu on a WordPress site that simply outputs all the child pages under that parent. I'm trying to highlight (or hopefully add an arrow) the current child page that is selected. I've run into a wall with my limited PHP experience to figure out how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The relevant code is below:

```
 <?php

                /* if the current pages has a parent, i.e. we are on a subpage */
                if($post->post_parent){
                    /* $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); // list the parent page */
                    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); // append the list of children pages to the same $children variable
                }

                /* else if the current page does not have a parent, i.e. this is a top level page */
                else {
                    //$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->ID."&echo=0");    // include the parent page as well
                    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&");   // form a list of the children of the current page
                }

                /* if we ended up with any pages from the queries above */
                if ($children) { ?>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <?php echo $children; /*print list of pages*/ ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
```

I'm assuming it would be in the  output section, but I simply don't know how to target the current child page that's being browsed and highlight that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little fun with this one. And my result might not be exactly what you were looking for, but I think it might be better. In short, the below snippet allows you to easily identify the page hierarchy (parent/children) for the current page. As such, you can then do all sorts of wonderful things to your heart's desire. For the purposes of your specific request, I made the custom function "custom_list_child_pages(...)" return a full list of links from the page hierarchy related to the "current page".

There is tons of logic, all related to the key situations you were trying to tackle. You should be able to identify when you are in a sub-page or parent page, you should be able to call out that little function and modify it to make it do whatever you need it to do with all the relevant players (current, parent [or self if no other], child pages, etc).

Let me know if this helps you and if you get stuck with the code or any other aspects regarding what you are trying to achieve let me know as well and I will see how I can assist you further.

**Code:**

```
<?php

//die(var_dump($foo)); // Quickly check a variable value.

function custom_list_child_pages($the_current_page_id, $the_parent_page_id, $child_pages){
   $html_page_listing = '';

   // Get creative with the parent page.
   $the_parent_page = get_page( $the_parent_page_id );
   $html_page_listing .= "<h3>" . "<a href='$the_parent_page->guid'>$the_parent_page->post_title</a>" . "</h3>";

   // Get creative with the child pages.
   $html_page_listing .= "<h3>" . "Child pages:" . "</h3>";

   $html_page_listing .= "<ul>";

   // Iterate through child pages as desired.
   foreach ($child_pages as $key => $page) {
      $current_page = get_page_by_title( $page->post_title );
      $current_page_id = $page->ID;

      if ($current_page_id == $the_current_page_id) {
         // Do something great.
         $html_page_listing .= "<li> ->" . "<a href='$page->guid'>$page->post_title</a>" . "</li>";
      } else {
         $html_page_listing .= "<li>" . "<a href='$page->guid'>$page->post_title</a>" . "</li>";
      }
   }
   $html_page_listing .= "</ul>";
   return $html_page_listing;
}

global $post; // If outside the loop.

// Set up the objects needed.
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
   // This is a subpage.
   $the_current_page_id = $page_id;
   $the_parent_page_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );

   $the_child_pages = get_page_children( $the_parent_page_id, $all_wp_pages ); // Form a list of the children of the current page.
   $the_parent_page_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID ); // Include the parent page as well.

   $menu = custom_list_child_pages($the_current_page_id, $the_parent_page_id, $the_child_pages); // ~append the list of children pages to the same $children variable
   echo $menu; // Print list of pages.

} else {
   // This is not a subpage.
   $the_current_page_id = $page_id;
   $the_parent_page_id = $page_id;

   $the_child_pages = get_page_children( $page_id, $all_wp_pages ); // Form a list of the children of the current page.
   $the_parent_page_id = $page_id; // Include the parent page as well.

   $menu = custom_list_child_pages($the_current_page_id, $the_parent_page_id, $the_child_pages);
   echo $menu; // Print list of pages.
}

?>
```

Regards,
Arty